# WooCommerce Get product ID in modal after Add to Cart (with ajax on product page)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using ajax for Add to Cart button on single product page, which is working fine. On successful ajax request it opens modal, I'm trying to get id of the added product and want to display some info in the modal but I'm unable to pass ID, I tried global variable and some other methods as well.

Here's my code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');

function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {

    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
    $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

        do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

        if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
        }

        WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
    } else {

        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

        echo wp_send_json($data);
    }

    wp_die();
}

<script type="text/javascript">

(function ($) {

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $thisbutton = jQuery(this),
                $form = $thisbutton.closest('form.cart'),
                id = $thisbutton.val(),
                product_qty = $form.find('input[name=quantity]').val() || 1,
                product_id = $form.find('input[name=product_id]').val() || id,
                variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val() || 0;

        var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: product_id,
            product_sku: '',
            quantity: product_qty,
            variation_id: variation_id,
        };

        jQuery(document.body).trigger('adding_to_cart', [$thisbutton, data]);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (response) {
                $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
            },
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.error & response.product_url) {
                    window.location = response.product_url;
                    return;
                } else {
                    jQuery(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
                }
                jQuery("#Modal").modal('show');
            },
        });

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

I want to pass id to this modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <?php echo $product_id; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!